# What are some possibilities in adding noise to training data to prevent overfitting when using closed form linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I had a very short discussion in class (zoom chat to be precise) about ways to prevent overfitting when using the normal equations (closed-form regression formula) to reduce overfitting on the training data.
I thought that adding some type of random noise to the training data should help.

The main question: Can you tell me about some known ways that we can add noise to the training data (no coefficient penalization) that should reduce overfitting?

Though I couldn't come up with anything good, I tried to add scaled random samples from normal distributions (generated using the mean and standard deviation of the training data) on this old kaggle competition:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/dont-overfit-ii/

In the end, it actually made overfitting worse (which intuitively makes sense, as I kind of reinforce the bias of the training data by using it's distribution), the auc score (on the test set) dropped from 0.5 to 0.4, which is worse than a random guess, I guess?

But it seems like if I can make it worse doing that, I should be able to make it better by doing the opposite? But what would the opposite of that be?

Thank you very much in advance!

I want to apologize in advance if this is very simplistic thinking, I am mainly curious and want to try out some things and I have been told by a TA that there are known ways (but he couldn't elaborate and hasn't answered yet)